# How to make JNLP voice chat application?

Tags: java, chat, jnlp, voice

I've seen some websites made a voice chat using .jnlp (Java Network Launch Protocol )

I was wondering how can I make a website the same like it, and how is that possible?
, link:

http://arbfoox.com/ | https://elhddbha.com/ | www . 63on . com

How cPanel looks like: www . 63on.com/server/server . html

in the cpanel list in the right it says:
Up~down.
Main, online now, rooms, colored names, banned, messages, server settings, password and log out.

When u click on 1 of the pictures it will download .jnlp file 2 kb and when u lunch it u will be asked to enter ur name then u will enter the chat, if u tried to edit that .jnlp file you will see how it works, just wondering how can I do the same in my website, and how can I make a cpanel for customers ect?

I was redirected to this website ivocalize . com < But when u try to use it, it doesn't look the same at all.

Answer (score 1):

JNLP is actually a really bad way to do this. If you want to make a web-based chat mechanism, consider using [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) (see also the [HTML5 rocks page on WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)), instead.

JNLP is basically a way of launching Java applications from a web browser. This has several downsides:

1. Java does not have the same sandbox/security model as typical browsers / web pages.
2. It does not work well on many platforms (e.g. Android, Chrome OS, etc.)
3. There have been a number of security incidents involving Java plugins in web browsers, as a result, web browsers often disable Java by default for security reasons. Thus you will need to tell users/customers how to enable Java/JNLP, whereas WebRTC works by default.

So, in short, please, please just use HTML5 (in particular the WebRTC API) rather than JNLP.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was just wondering how is that work and I will look into these links.

Comment: JNLP is basically just Java code that has been specially packaged. If you were to write it as JNLP, you'd basically create an ordinary Java desktop application, and then you'd worry about packaging it using JNLP at the very end. It's pretty much just a signed JAR file plus a ".jnlp" XML file that describes the JAR and associated resources.